# Why does \overline mess up the spacing?

Tags: spacing

Consider `$a \triangleright b$` and `$a \overline{\triangleright} b$`.
They behave completely different in terms of spacing:

[image]

Why? How do I fix that?

Comment: You would enclose the object, `\overline{\triangleright}`, in the appropriate math terminology macro, of which the choices, in general, are  `\mathpunct`, `\mathop`, `\mathrel`, `\mathbin`, and `\mathord`,

Comment: `\mathbin{\overline\triangleright}`

Comment: And if used often, wrap LaRiFaRis solution in a `\newcommand`

Comment: So is there a way to "keep the way the spacing was before", so the `\overline` would work with characters as well?

Comment: Sure: `\newcommand*{\mboverline}[1]{\mathbin{\overline#1}}`. You could even redefine the old `\overline`, but you will not have a lot of pleasure with this later on...

Comment: @LaRiFaRi, but if I do `$a \mboverline{/} b$`, the spacing is the wrong one, compared to $a / b$.

Comment: @Turion Yes. The / is one of the binary operators which we do not want to behave as `\mathbin` (talking about the spacing explained in my answer). You would need to write `\overline{/}` here. If you really need a `\newcommand*{\eggLayingWoolMilkSow}[1]{\crazyStuff\overline{#1}}` for your paper, you should define the scope of possible appearances in your question. As Steven wrote above: There could be a lot of different stuff, you are trying to overline here.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes The sequences `\mathbin`, `\mathop` etc. are not macros byt they are TeX primitives.

Comment: @wipet You are so right.  Thank you for that correction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command `\triangleright` is a so called binary operator. LaTeX treats this binary operators in a way, that a small horizontal space is set before and after it. What happened here is that you have wrapped this command in some other command which does hide this feature. You can see the same effect if you just try `$a+b{+}c$`.

Therefore, you will have to make your construct a binary operator again by wrapping it in the command `\mathbin`:

```
 % arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\oltriangleright}{\mathbin{\overline\triangleright}}

\begin{document}
$a \triangleright b$ and $a \oltriangleright b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

What does this symbol mean? If you have some reference, you might recommend it to the unicode.

Comment: I'm using `\overline` as an operation that can be applied to many objects, for example the triangle, but also to variables, so I don't think it justifies a definition on its own.

Comment: @Turion You can always do it manually or you use the command I posted as comment above.

Comment: If the symbol represents a relation, should it not be `mathrel`?

Comment: @Raphael If it does, of course. As I have no idea about the meaning and as `\triangleright` is a binary operator, I suggested the new symbol to be one, too.

Answer (score 4):

Each object in math typesetting has one of the classes: 0=Ord, 1=Op, 2=Bin, 3=Rel, 4=Open, 5=Close, 6=Punct. This class influences the horizontal spaces (automatically inserted between objects). The elementary objects in math typesetting are typically declared by `\mathchardef` primitive (for control sequences) or `\mathcode` (for native codes). The `\mathode` of `a` and `b` are declared as class Ord and triangleright is declared as

```
\mathchardef\triangleright="212E
```

which means class=2=Bin, family=1, fontcode=2E. The most important (for now) is the class Bin. The sequence `a\triangleright b` is "Ord Bin Ord" and this influences the right horizontal spaces. The things are more complicated, but the basic principle is shown here.

Now, the most important is the fact that braces (like `{\triangleright}`) or other constructions (like `\overline{\triangleright}`) creates the composed object in the class Ord. So, we have `Ord Ord Ord` in our example and this inserts none spaces between. But there are class-retyping primitives `\mathord`, `\mathop`, `\mathbin`, `\mathrel`, `\mathopen`, `\mathclose` and `\mathpunct` which generates the object of given class. So

```
a \mathbin{\overline{\triangleright}} b
```

gives the sequence "Ord Bin Ord" and this influences the right spacing.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the correct spacing using a modified version of `\overline` that uses the same infrastructure as `\overset`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\coverline}[1]{% clever overline
  \binrel@{#1}\binrel@@{\overline{#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a\coverline{<}b$

$a<b$

$a\coverline{\triangleright} b$

$a\triangleright b$

\end{document}
```

The instruction `\binrel@` determines whether the argument is a binary operation or relation symbol and sets `\binrel@@` to mean `\mathbin` or `\mathrel` accordingly; if the type cannot be determined, it is set to `\mathord`.

[image]