# Overline in operator messes spacing

Tags: spacing, math-operators

I wish to define an operator, something like:

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\St}{\overline{St}}
```

It works partially, however the spacing between the operator and the next symbol disappears.

May I ask how to correct this? I tried doing:

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\St}{\mathop{\overline{St}}}
```

enclosing a `\mathop` as suggested in [Why does \overline mess up the spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241414/why-does-overline-mess-up-the-spacing). However, it doesn't seem to work in this context.

Thanks for any help.

Update: Sorry, my bad, I put a curly bracket `{\St}` in my code, which causes the spacing to disappear. Removing the curly bracket solves the issue.

Comment: @David There remains a spacing issue between the operator and a superscript.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek there are any number of issues not mentioned in the  question in code that isn't shown:-) But no matter now you've answered the close vote can be ignored (I'll delete the close comment)

Answer (score 6):

The subscript seems fine. But the superscript is pretty close to the line.
The line can be shortened:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\StA}{\overline{St}}

% Line shortened by \thinmuskip
\DeclareMathOperator{\StC}{\overline{St\!}\,}

% Line shortend by .5\thinmuskip
\DeclareMathOperator{\StB}{%
  \overline{St\mskip-.5\thinmuskip}\mskip.5\thinmuskip
}

\begin{document}
\[
  \StA_{0}^{n}\;
  \StB_{0}^{n}\;
  \StC_{0}^{n}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The middle version `\StB` seems acceptable.